# Отключение Plug&Play

Tags: winapi, реестр, c#

Привет ребята! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отключить службу Plug&Play? Мне надо, чтобы при удалении устройства из диспетчера устройств, после перезагрузки оно не определялось автоматически. Сделать это желательно, для меня, через реестр либо как-то программно, используя WinAPI...

Вот некоторая информация, которую я обработал, но она мне не помогла:

- http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1131/
- http://www.pc1news.com/disabling-universal-plug-and-play-services-1131.html
- http://www.liutilities.com/products/registrybooster/tweaklibrary/tweaks/10533/

Делал так, как тут написано... но после рестарта системы устройства автоматически обнаруживались.

Заранее очень благодарен за инфу!
Успехов всем ;)

Comment: По указанным ссылкам речь идёт вовсе не о выключении Plug&Play, а об отключении UnPnP (определение сетевых устройств).

Comment: Посмотрите на этот ответ, здесь  рассматривается включение/отключение устройства на C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programatically-enable-disable-device

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, но мне не нужно отключать УСТРОЙСТВО, мне нужно отключать АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ УСТРОЙСТВ

Comment: сделайте так как описано в 1ой ссылке а потом отредактируйте permission для этой ветки реестра (уберите галочки для write) что заблокирует эту ветку от изменения (т.е система когда будет находить устройство просто будет считывать состояние "отклчено")

как вариант поискать что-то в настройках безопасности системы/домена

Answer (score 2):

Его не нужно удалять, просто отключите его:

1. идем в диспетчер устройств
2. заходим в свойства устройства и внизу, где написано "Применение устройства" указываем, что оно отключено.

Все, больше оно вас не побеспокоит. Если делать программно, то ищите функции WinAPI, если через реестр, то надо знать, что за устройство и где хранится о нем инфа в реестре, думаю, будет параметр что-нибудь типа Enabled или DeviceEnabled.

Answer (score 1):

Для отключения устройства программным путем можно пользовать утилиту devcon: [использование программы с интерфейсом командной строки DevCon в качестве альтернативы диспетчеру устройств](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272).

> `devcon disable`
> Отключить устройства, которые соответствуют определенному идентификатору оборудования или экземпляра.

Вы можете вызвать ее из своего кода на C#. Также можно взять WDK, там, по-моему, были исходники этой утилиты, и работать через тот же API, что использует devcon.